# How can I combine multiple regression models?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, finance, forecast-combination

I'm trying to predict some financial feature (continuous) and there are two or more good regression models. Is it possible to combine multiple regression models? If so, what kind of method is it called?

Comment: Some relevant keywords are *model averaging* and *forecast combination*. There are books and chapters on the topic, e.g. Burnham & Anderson ["Model Selection and Multimodel Inference"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97636) (2002) and Claeskens & Hjort ["Model Selection and Model Averaging"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/model-selection-and-model-averaging/E6F1EC77279D1223423BB64FC3A12C37) (2008). Check out the tag that I added, too.

Comment: Welcome to CV, 070701.  The possible answers cover a lot of ground and depend on the particulars, including how those models might be related to one another, whether they share any data, and your analytical objectives.  Please edit your post to include enough information that we can offer effective and appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [Ensemble Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning). Where the predictions of multiple models are aggregated. One simple strategy is to use the average of the predictions. Additionally, people use the standard deviation of the different predicted values as a simple measure of the uncertainty.